# Ajuda com adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth?

Tags: swift, xcode

Ao usar o adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth na segunda outlet eu recebo erro.

Alguém sabe como solucionar?

Obs.: A segunda view controller está como a primeira, na mesma classe!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var botaoIniciar: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var botaoBrasil: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {    
        super.viewDidLoad()
        botaoIniciar.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        botaoIniciar.titleLabel?.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
        botaoBrasil.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        botaoBrasil.titleLabel?.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloca o erro que está sendo gerado.

Comment: thread1: EXC_BAD_INTRUCTON (code=EXC+I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

Comment: mas so acontece pro por causa da segunda  viewcontroller estar na classe desse documento swift , o primeiro botao que esta na primera  viewcontroller esta rodando normal ! o baseline tbm nao roda ! sera que tenho que usar algum metodo delegate

Comment: creio que o erro está no se storyboard